# Reducer shows undefined even though event is passed to dispatcher

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dom-events

I have the following component with redux integrated and a reducer specifically for this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './generalinfo.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// import 'icheck/skins/flat/aero.css';
import { Checkbox, Radio } from 'react-icheck';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class GeneralInfo extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div className={ classes.screen2 } >
                <table className={ classes.initial__survey__details__table }>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Gender    
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    Age    
                            </td>     
                        </tr>     
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="customer_gender" onChange={ (e) => this.props.validateRadioInput(e) } />                                     
                                <label>Male</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="customer_age" onChange={ (e) => this.props.validateRadioInput(e) } />                                   
                                <label>Less than 35</label>
                            </td>     
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="customer_gender" onChange={ (e) => this.props.validateRadioInput(e) } />                                    
                                <label>Female</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="customer_age" onChange={ (e) => this.props.validateRadioInput(e) } />                                    
                                <label>More than 35</label>
                            </td>     
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="2">
                                <Link to="/preferences" className={ [classes.btn , classes["btn--fullwidth"] , classes.btn__next  ].join(' ') } 
                                        onClick={ this._ToggleNextScreenButton } >
                                    Next
                                </Link>
                            </td>   
                        </tr>     
                    </tbody>   
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        infoObj : state.gen
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        validateRadioInput : (e) => dispatch({ type: 'VALI_RADIO_INP' , elem : e })
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GeneralInfo);
```

As you can see `onChange` I have the following function that runs:

```
onChange={ (e) => this.props.validateRadioInput(e) }
```

somehow in my reducer if in console.log the element passed, I get undefined, my reducer looks like below:

```
const initialState = {
    genderRadioClick : false,
    ageRadioClick : false
}

const reducer = (  state = initialState , action , payload ) => {

    switch(action.type) {
        case "VALI_RADIO_INP":
            console.log(payload) // i get undefined here ! why ?
            return state        
    }
    return state;
}

export default reducer;
```

The dispatcher function looks like below:

```
  validateRadioInput : (e) => dispatch({ type: 'VALI_RADIO_INP' , elem : e })
```

Why am I getting `undefined` in my reducer, even though I am passing the `event` to the function?

**NOTE::-** if I pass `e.target` I get it in the reducer, only passing `e` gives me undefined, does this have something to do with the fact that `e` is an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you incorrect getting and setting payload:

Corrected action:

```
  validateRadioInput : (e) => dispatch({ type: 'VALI_RADIO_INP' , payload : e })
```

Corrected reducer:

```
const reducer = (  state = initialState , action) => {

switch(action.type) {
    case "VALI_RADIO_INP":
        console.log(action.payload) // i get undefined here ! why ?
        return state        
 }
  return state;
}

 export default reducer;
```

Comment: @Alexander Solonik, try to console.log and see if the payload present

Comment: @Alexander Solonik nice)